# Image texture is not mapping correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I unwrapped part of my mesh (front of an iphone screen) and added the image texture. [image]

Strange things are happening but this image texture is not mapping correctly. What is wrong and how to solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Your screen model seems to be split in half across the middle, that could be causing some problems.  My guess is the root of the problem is the subsurf though.

Comment: I tried a few things after the comment of PGmath but to be honest ... I have no clue how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in the UV Mapping.

[image]

To fix theme, select the faces with Screen Material in the Material Panel,

[image]

then UV map "Project from View (Bounds)" (<kbd>U</kbd> -> Project from View).

If you disable the Subsurf modifier, it works.
To fix the Subsurf issue, add an *edge loop* near the external edges of the screen.
[image]

Comment: hmm ... I thought I have tried that (to Mark Seam the edges of the screen).