# Assign Material goes over the selection

Tags: materials, faces

Trying to assign a material to a face of a mesh and always this happens. It goes over the selection. All the weird things happen to me. :P[image]

Comment: Are you using a subsurf modifier?

Comment: "Are you using a subsurf modifier?" Yes!

Comment: Should i apply the subsurf? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: no need to appy it use an edge loop to create denser geometry where you need the material to stop.

Comment: related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42737/image-texture-is-not-mapping-correctly/42842#42842

Comment: If you enable the [triangle in the modifier header](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) you will see where the edges are after the subsurf has altered it.